# Can someone check if I have found all the cyclic subgroups of $D_3$

Tags: group-theory

I have been asked to find all the cyclic subgroups of $D_3$ and therefore determine if $D_3$ has a non-cyclic subgroup.

So I have set $D_3$=$G$ and therefore:

$G=${$e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b$}

The cyclic subgroups I have found are: {$e$}, {$b,e$}, {$ab,e$}, {$a^2b,e$} and {$a, a^2, e$}

There is no element of $G$ that has order 6, so $G$ itself is a non-cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Have I got this correct?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: However since the proper divisors of $|D_3|$ are $1,2,3$, there are no proper non-cyclic subgroups.  This might have been the point of the problem, since otherwise it would have been more natural simply to as if $D_3 = S_3$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $D_6$ or $D_3$ has those cyclic subgroups. Note that $$(a^2)^2=a^4=a\\(a^2)^3=(a^3)^2=1\\ (a^2)^4=a^8=a^6\cdot a^2=a^2$$ and so $\langle a^2\rangle=\langle a\rangle$. However, $(2,3)=1$ and so might get this result already. Also, $$(a^2b)^2=(a^2b)(a^2b)=a^2(ba^2)b=a^2(a^{-1}ba)b=(ab)^2=1$$ so as you noted correctly $\{a^2b,1\}$ is a proper subgroup. Remember $S_3\cong D_6$.

Comment: Nice observations! +1